# PyQt getOpenFileName default directory

Tags: macos, python-2.7, pyqt, pyqt4, qfiledialog

I'm using Qt.Gui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName method to open a file. If I set the default file directory to `"/Users/me/Documents/data/2013/today/"` the dialog box opens to `"/Users/me/Documents/data/2013/"` with the `"today"` folder selected. How do I get the the correct default folder to be opened in the window?

```
fname = QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Open file', "/Users/me/Documents/data/2012/20121102/images/",'*.npy')
```

Opens a dialog box in `/Users/me/Documents/data/2012/20121102`. I want the window to open in `/Users/me/Documents/data/2012/20121102/images/`

Answer (score 1):

For someone's information (even though 8 years passed)

You could pass the `directory` argument to `getOpenFileName` for the default folder in PyQt5.

Answer (score 0):

The most probable reason is that the file doesn't exist at the time you are requesting it be opened. For opening folders use [`QtGui.QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory`](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/4.8/qfiledialog.html#getExistingDirectory):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#-*- coding:utf-8 -*-

from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class MyWindow(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        self.pushButtonOpen = QtGui.QPushButton(self)
        self.pushButtonOpen.setText("Open Folder")
        self.pushButtonOpen.clicked.connect(self.on_pushButtonOpen_clicked)

        self.layoutHorizontal = QtGui.QHBoxLayout(self)
        self.layoutHorizontal.addWidget(self.pushButtonOpen)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def on_pushButtonOpen_clicked(self):
        folderName = QtGui.QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(
            self, "Open Directory",
            "/path/to/folder",
            QtGui.QFileDialog.ShowDirsOnly | QtGui.QFileDialog.DontResolveSymlinks,
        )

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setApplicationName('MyWindow')

    main = MyWindow()
    main.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: I don't want to return the directory. The returned string can be parsed to get the directory if needed. I want the OpenFileDialog window to open in the correct directory. I edited the question to clarify.

Comment: @JMD I am not getting that behavior in my Debian OS, please double check your question and checkout my [updated answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15634376/1006989)